# How to specify change directory in heroku procfile in a node js app

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a simple nodejs web application.But the **App.js** file is in another directory!
So how do i specify the changed directory like ***CD the folder name*** and run the app in the heroku procfile?!

Answer (score 0):

write this line

`web: node [The directory path to app.js]`

Comment: can i write "Cd "the folder name" && app.js" ?

Comment: Why you need to overwork on `Procfile`  and `Procfile` does't work in that way. Just use `web: node thefoldername/app.js`